# How to decode null to empty string in Circe

Tags: scala, circe

I have the following case class

```
case class Response(attributes: CsvAttributes, rows: Seq[Array[String]])
```

The `rows` are obtained from a Java library which can have null elements in the array as shown below:

```
[
  ["a", "b", null],
  ["c", null, "d"]
]
```

`Response(attributes, rows).asJson.noSpaces` throws error.

How to encode the null elements into empty string("")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a custom decoder for `Response`:

```
implicit val decodeResponse: Decoder[Response] = (c: HCursor) =>
  for {
    attributes <- c.downField("attributes").as[CsvAttributes]
    rows       <- c.downField("rows").as[Seq[Array[Option[String]]]]
  } yield {
    Response(attributes, rows.map(_.map {
      case Some(v) => v
      case None    => ""
    }))
  }
```

I would try to translate the response from your Java library to idiomatic Scala (e.g. translate `null` to `Option.None`).

But in case you want to avoid this, you can overwrite the default behaviour of how circe encodes a `String`. This declaration would change it to represent `null` with an empty string:

```
implicit val encodeFoo: Encoder[String] = {
  case null => Json.fromString("")
  case s    => Json.fromString(s)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If we have to iterate then I can directly create newRows with `null` values replaced with `""` and then use `Response(attributes, newRows).asJson.noSpaces`

Comment: In general you should avoid `null` in Scala. You can use `Option.None` to represent `null` values. In case you need some more input, I could add it to my answer. Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Another quick and dirty approach is:

```
implicit val encodeString = 
  Encoder.encodeString.contramap[String](s => if (s == null) "" else s)
```